# Could my data have been accessed on my lost iPhone 4 with iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ios

Yesterday, someone stole my iPhone 4 (it was updated with iOS 7), but iCloud backup was not enabled. My iPhone was locked with a 4 digit passkey.

I have confidential personal data on my iPhone, and I dont want this data to be accessed. I did quick search with 'Play sound', 'Lost mode'. After almost 1 hour I decide to use the 'Erase iPhone' option.

One hour later it shows me that my iPhone was erased.

I have the below questions:

1. Is it possible that my peronal data was accessed by the thief? even before I started the Lost mode and Erase iPhone options?
2. Is it possible that my iPhone was accessed through iTunes?
3. Since the iPhone was shown in iCloud as 'Erased', does it mean the iPhone was for sure connected to Internet? How does he enable Wi-Fi if there was a required 4 digit passkey?
4. Is there any extra protection with iOS 7?

Answer (score 1):

1. It is only possible if the thief knew (or guessed) your passcode.
2. If your data was in standard apps(Mail, safari), then there's nothing to worry about, if it was stored in apps that allow for filesharing through the 'apps'-tab on iTunes, then I don't really know how iTunes handles that.
3. Yes it was connected to the Internet, but it could be with 3G (was it on when it was stolen?) or a public network that automatically connects (like Apple Stores or Starbucks) without needing a password.
4. Don't really know

In any case, report this to your local police office (bring the serial number, it should be on the box) and let them handle the theft.

Answer (score 0):

4) Is you enable 'find my iphone' in iOs7, the user won't be able to format your phone till he is able to login your Apple-ID account.

Eg using itunes -> Restore phone will fail and require to login first. Practical, the phone `should` be completely unusable now